# Page Headings and Functions with their headings

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one more question for the day. I'm trying to make my biography page totally customizable for my custom CMS project I'm doing. If you notice in the view I have 3 h2 tags for Quotes, Allies, Rivals. What I would like to do is put the h3's into my db and then have it do a foreach loop for each one of them so I'm thinking some how I"m going to have to store the function that goes with the pageheading that way it doesn't have to run it if its not active on the page. I know this can be easily done however there's too much for me to focus on what I need to do in order to complete this. Keep in mind that depending on which page you are in the bio will impact which headings will be available.

As of right now here is my controller:

```
$activeTemplate = $this->sitemodel->getTemplate();
    $footerLinks = $this->sitemodel->getFooterNav();
    $bodyContent = "bio";//which view file
    $bodyType = "main";//type of template
    $this->data['activeTemplate'] = $activeTemplate;
    $this->data['footerLinks']= $footerLinks;
    $this->load->model('biomodel');
    if($character !== "jfkdlsjl")
    {
        if((!empty($character))||(!isset($character))||(trim($character) !== '')||($character !== NULL))
        {
            $bioArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterBio($character);
            if ($bioArray == "empty")
            {
                $this->data['bioArray']= array();
            }
            else
            {
                if (($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 2)||($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 3)||($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 5))
                {
                    $this->data['bioArray']= array(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->data['bioArray']= $bioArray;
                    $bioPagesArray = $this->biomodel->getBioPages();
                    $alliesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterAllies($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $rivalsArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterRivals($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $quotesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterQuotes($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $this->data['bioPagesArray']= $bioPagesArray;
                    $this->data['alliesArray']= $alliesArray;
                    $this->data['rivalsArray']= $rivalsArray;
                    $this->data['quotesArray']= $quotesArray;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my view:

```
echo "<h2>Quotes</h2>";
    if (!empty($quotesArray)) 
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        for($x = 0; $x <= (count($quotesArray)-1); $x++)
        {
            echo "<li>".stripslashes($quotesArray[$x]->quote)."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "<h2>Allies</h2>";
    if (!empty($alliesArray)) 
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($alliesArray as $row)
        {
            echo "<li>".stripslashes($row)."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "<h2>Rivals</h2>";
    if (!empty($rivalsArray)) 
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($rivalsArray as $row)
        {
            echo "<li>".stripslashes($row)."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean about storing the function nor which function you don't want to run.

Assuming we're working with the last `else` statement in your controller

```
$alliesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterAllies($bioArray[0]->id);
$rivalsArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterRivals($bioArray[0]->id);
$quotesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterQuotes($bioArray[0]->id);
```

... and the function you "don't want to run" is the `foreach` loop on the array in the view,  just handle the logic in your view:

```
if(($this->uri->segment(n)=='pageIwantQuotesOn') && (!empty($quotesArray)){
    echo "<h2>Quotes</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";
    for($x = 0; $x <= (count($quotesArray)-1); $x++)
    {
        echo "<li>".stripslashes($quotesArray[$x]->quote)."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
...
```